# Url missing action after model failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a profile controller action UPDATE which updates a user's account information.  If the model is deemed invalid, I want to render my EDIT action like this:

```
if @user.valid?
  #update
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

The URL for the EDIT action is /my_profile/edit.  However, when the *render 'edit'* code is processed upon failure, even though the correct view is displayed with appropriate errors, the URL that is loaded is /my_profile.

When I'm editing a profile on /my_profile/edit, how can I get the URL /my_profile/edit to be loaded when I call the EDIT action upon model failure?

Here are the current, applicable routes:

```
get 'my_profile' => 'my_profile#show'
get 'my_profile/edit' => 'my_profile#edit', as: 'edit_my_profile'
put 'my_profile' => 'my_profile#update'
```

Answer (score 0):

Info: I'm also a beginner!
I thought "render" means, that only the view 'edit' will be rendered.
If you wanted a new request (which changes your also your url and goes in your edit action in the controller) you need an

```
redirect_to 'edit'
```

or am I on the wrong way?